# java xml uploading problem!

Tags: java, xml, upload, ftp, network-programming

I am having a situation here which I need to resolve. I have to upload particular elements of an xml file to upload it to a server, managed to do that, and I created a demo method to check if the file is being uploaded to the server or not.

My xml file has the structure,

```
<config>
 <engine>
    <eid>1</eid>
    <sometextelement>text</sometextelement>
 </engine>

 <engine>
    <eid>2</eid>
    <sometextelement>text</sometextelement>
 </engine>

 <engine>
    <eid>3</eid>
    <sometextelement>text</sometextelement>
 </engine>


</config>
```

My servlet code is:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        //response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
         PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
         JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
         String value = request.getParameter("value");
            String message = "";
            String update = "";
            Element element = null;
            Element root = null;

            XMLOutputter xmlOutputter = new XMLOutputter();
        try{
        doc = saxBuilder.build("E:/workbench j2ee/cPEP_UI/WebContent/engine.xml");

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        root = doc.getRootElement();
        List list = doc.getRootElement().getChildren();
        Iterator itr = list.iterator();
        int i = 0;
        while(itr.hasNext()){
             element = (Element)itr.next();
            System.out.println("Entered 1");
          File f = File.createTempFile("engine_",".xml");
           System.out.println(f);
            xmlOutputter.output(element, new FileWriter(f));

            i += 1;


            putFile(f,i);



        }




         // xmlOutputter.output(doc, new FileWriter("E:/workbench j2ee/cPEP_UI/WebContent/engine.xml"));





        // System.out.println("hello from system");
        // out.println("hello");



    }

    public void putFile(File f, int i) throws SocketException, IOException{
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        FileInputStream fis = null;

        client.connect("ftp.someserver.co.uk",21);
        boolean login = client.login("webmaster@someserver.co.uk",
                "mypassword");



        fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        if(client.storeFile("engine_"+i+".xml", fis)){
            System.out.println("yes");
        }else{
            System.out.println("no");

        }
        client.logout();
        fis.close();
    }
```

But the problem is, the file is getting uploaded properly, but the content is not complete, what I mean to say is, the `<engine>` is there but `</engine>` is not there. But I rechecked it in my local system, which is creating a temporary file, and it shows the complete xml file. Why the whole content is not being uploaded to the server!?
any ideas?
This is what I am seeing in the server,

```
<engine>
    <eid>1</eid>
    <sometextelement
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wrote the client code yourself, this looks like the client-side stream isn't flushed correctly.

Try flushing or closing (`close()` flushes a stream as well) the client stream.

Comment: I didnt get you Vivien! there is not method fis.flush().

Comment: how to do that?! Please help me out with this!

Comment: On the client side, when you are uploading the file. What are you using? Probably some kind of OutputStream, with a ``flush()`` method.

Comment: I am using the method putFile(), whose code is already there in the question. but theres not flush method related to any stream i am using.

Comment: In this case, that might be the ``new FileWriter(f)`` you are using to store your temporary xml file.

Comment: yes, I am using the  ` new FileWriter(f)` in `xmlOutputter` object, but I dont know the way how to flush it out after that, as i am not creating any object of FileWriter.